# openssl_pkey_get_private и переносы строк

Tags: php

Есть private key в виде строки с переносом строк \n :

```
$key = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBAD..manysymbols..\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
```

Данный ключ должен обрабатываться функцией [openssl_pkey_get_private](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php)  и возвращать объект ресурса.

Но данная функция не работает, а [openssl_error_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-error-string.php) выдает ошибку "no start line error"

Проблема была найдена - переносы строк \n . Есть следующие варианты событий:

1) Оставляем строку без изменений - функция выдает ошибку.

2) Убираем \n - функция выдает ошибку.

3) Вместо \n делаем переносы строк в редакторе и переводим в HERE-DOC - функция работает.

4) Вместо \n делаем переносы строк и сохраняем в файл. Ключ берем уже из файла обычным file_get_contents - функция работает.

Собственно, как обработать изначальную строку с помощью php, чтобы не переводить ее вручную в многострочный формат?

Comment: Переносы, вставленные в редакторе, это скорее всего \r\n. Может, в этом и дело?

Comment: Этот вариант пробовал, к сожалению проблему не исправляет